# bash case statement with unmatched patterns

Tags: bash, scripting, case

Ok, so i have tried searching for this on google and i cant seem to find an answer. What i'm trying to do is create a case statement in bash but if the user enters a different number than listed it just exits the script. How do i make it give an error and then ask for the user to select one of the options?

for example, my case statement

```
case $ans in
1) echo "Running Project 1..."
   sleep 2
   ./project1.sh
;;
2) echo "Running Project 2..."
   sleep 2
   ./project2.sh
;;
Qq) echo "Exiting"
    exit
;;
esac
```

so any options other than 1, 2, Qq it will give an error saying invalid selection, try again.

Comment: I just tried wrapping an if statement around case statment and it still doesn't work, maybe my if statement is wrong? `if [ $ans == "1" || $ans == "2" || $ans == "q" || $ans == "Q" ]`

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the `select` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a while loop and a boolean variable like that:

```
flag = true
while [  $flag ]; do
    case $ans in
        1) echo "Running Project 1..."
           sleep 2
           ./project1.sh
        ;;
        2) echo "Running Project 2..."
           sleep 2
           ./project2.sh
        ;;
        Qq) echo "Exiting"
            flag = false
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: initially this did not work for me but then i moved my read statment for `$ans` inside the loop and it works. However, the when i try to quit the `Qq` no longer works. but if i take one q out the other works. Without creating a 4th case option, how do i keep it to its `Q` or `q` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the proper way or not but i changed `Qq)` to `Q|q)` and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right as you can see [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case) the syntax of OR between two patterns

Comment: also i changed the while loop around a bit. First for the `Q|q)` choice instead of having it exit from that choice i had it set the flag to false. In the while loop i changed it to `while [ $flag = "true" ];do` instead, so once the exit choice is selected it changes the value to false and the loop exits. This way allows me to run more commands if i need to.